# Git version error when calling heroku commands - Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, heroku, rubygems

I'm new to Heroku, so this has be stuck.  I can work with heroku, but when I do something like a rake command, I get this error all of the time:

```
PS C:\rails\testApp> heroku rake db:migrate
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:110:in ``': No such file or dir
sion  (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:110:in `has_git?'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:115:in `git'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:192:in `git_r
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:170:in `extra
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:29:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:74:in `rake'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/lib/heroku/command.rb:135:in `send'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/lib/heroku/command.rb:135:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/lib/heroku/cli.rb:9:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/heroku-2.21.2/bin/heroku:21
        from C:/Ruby187/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby187/bin/heroku:19
```

The weird thing is that the heroku commands will work in the end, but I also can't rule out that this might be causing some side effects downstream.  I've asked some of my Mac-based colleagues and they think this is some windows-only issue but since this error is from the gem directory I don't want to muck with that file if I don't have to.

The helper's source with the error is:

```
def has_git?
  %x{ git --version }
  $?.success?
end
```

so obviously git isn't being seen, when in fact I'm using git.  I'm using the Git Bach for my work there, is it something where I need to link powershell/heroku to git in someway?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I realized that I can just use the Git Bash for the heroku commands which solved the problem.  So I have powershell for rails work and git bash for git/heroku plus and IDE open for code.  Seems like a lot, but it's working.